# How to pass today date in requests params Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, celery

I have celery function which sends a request to API on every 5 minutes and get some JSON data.

I want to know how to pass today date in params to this request for example:

Full data will be 15k lines but if i pass today date to param I'll get only 1k lines.

tasks.py

```
def create_presence_info():
    payload = {'today_date': today} # this is an example idk what i should write there
    url = config('PRESENCE_INFO')
    response = requests.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH)
```

Comment: not enough information in the question to know what you need. Does the api accept a date? If so under what name is it expecting. If you are using the requests library, look into the 'json' or 'data' arguments.  see: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request and the last note in this section: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`django.utils.timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) module to get the current date and time in the timezone specified in your Django settings, like the following:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def create_presence_info():
    today = timezone.localdate().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    payload = {'today_date': today}
    url = config('PRESENCE_INFO')
    response = requests.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH, params=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for now or today, you can use:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...
def create_presence_info():
    today = timezone.now()
    payload = {'today_date': today} # this is an example idk what i should write there
    url = config('PRESENCE_INFO')
    response = requests.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH, data=payload)
    # but this might be what you need:
    # response = requests.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH, json=payload)
```

See the documentation under:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts

for some further reading.